# Modify a label FOR attribute

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery function to clone a DIV that contains a set of input elements:

```
<div class="history-form-fields">

<div class="row">
  <label for="History_0_type">Type</label>
  <select name="History[0][type]" id="History_0_type">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <label for="History_0_name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="History[0][name]" id="History_0_name" />
</div>

<div class="row">
  <label for="History_0_year">Year</label>
  <select name="History[0][year]" id="History_0_year">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>

<input id="addAnother" type="button" value="Add Another" />
```

When this DIV gets cloned the input elements NAME and ID tags need to be modified so that we can identify the data in the server side script.

I have the following code that clones the DIV and modifies the INPUT and SELECT tags:

```
var counter = 0;

$('#addAnother').click(function(){
    var divCloned = $('.history-form-fields:first').clone();
    divCloned.insertAfter('.history-form-fields:last');
    initNewInputs(divCloned.children('.row'), ++counter);
});

function initNewInputs(divs, idNumber)
{       
    var inputs = divs.children('input, select').get(); // find all the INPUT and SELECT tags

    for(var i in inputs)
    {
        inputs[i].id = inputs[i].id.replace(/\d+/, idNumber);
        inputs[i].name = inputs[i].name.replace(/\d+/, idNumber);
    }
}
```

However I am having trouble modifying the LABEL FOR attributes. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `for` is a Javascript keyword, the HTML `for` attribute is exposed by the `htmlFor` property in Javascript.

However, you can replace your loop by a single jQuery call and avoid this issue:

```
divs.children('label').attr('for',
    function(index, old) { return old.replace(/\d+/, idNumber); }
);
```

Comment: Cheers mate. Can the "inputs" for loop also be replaced like this?

Comment: @GSTAR: Yes, it can.  However, you'll need two `attr` calls.  You might want to write `var replacer = function(index, old) { return old.replace(/\d+/, idNumber); };` and pass that.

Comment: Hi SLaks - just one more question - at the time of modifying the FOR attribute I also wish to add a 'class' attribute to the same label tag (using attr() function) - any way to integrate this into this new code?

Comment: @GSTAR: You can write `$(this).addClass(...)` inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Tag Attributes can be accessed through the .attr() function.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you already have an acceptable javascript answer... but another way you could handle this is by changing your html.  If you move the input and select controls inside the label you wouldn't need to fix the "for" attribute.

```
<div class="history-form-fields">
    <div class="row">
        <label>
            Type
            <select name="History[0][type]" id="History_0_type">
                <option value="">Select</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>
            Name
            <input type="text" name="History[0][name]" id="History_0_name" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>
            Year
            <select name="History[0][year]" id="History_0_year">
                <option value="">Select</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea... is that Valid Markup though?